# Downloading only images using curl or wget?

Tags: download, http, wget, curl, mime-types

### UPDATED:

I've found using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7321/rename-music-files-with-missing-file-extensions) Bash script fixes the problem of having GIF files with a .jpg extension.

---

I'm attempting to download images from a forum who's url uses the following format:

`http://www.someforum.com/attachment.php&id=XXX`

I wrote a bash script that uses `wget` to retrieve these images:

```
for i in {1..10}

do
    wget --accept .jpg,.jpeg --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt -p "http://www.someforum.com/attachment.php&id=${i}" -O "image${i}.jpg"

done
```

It works and downloads the images. However if there isn't an image it still downloads the resulting HTML and stuffs it in `XX.jpg`.

Curl does the same:

```
for i in {1..10}

do
    curl --cookie cookies.txt "http://www.someforum.com/attachment.php&id=${i}" -o "image${i}.jpg"

done
```

Is there anyway to reject results that are not `/image/*`? Right now I am assuming that the images are jpeg, it would be nice to detect the MIME/TYPE and use the appropriate filename.

Finally, wget is giving 500 response codes when an image isn't found, if I can filter 200 response codes this may yield a solution.

Bash, Ruby, Python answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wget returns a non-zero exit code on error; it specifically sets exit status == 8 if the remote issued a 4xx or 5xx status.  So, you can modify your bash loop to unlink the file if wget doesn't exit with success:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    wget --accept .jpg,.jpeg --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt -p "http://www.someforum.com/attachment.php&id=${i}" -O "image${i}.jpg" || rm "image${i}.jpg"
done
```

Similarly, curl has a --fail option, with which it wont save the file and returns exit status 22 when the http status is >= 400.

Comment: This works, thank you. I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anybody comments regarding MIME/Content-Type as I'm still (understandably) getting `GIF` files saved as `.jpg`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you had files saved with wrong extension problem too. I would have suggested `file --mime` to map the appropriate real extension too.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid post processing but having looked through the entire wget manual it seems as though it's the only way.